# Poor performance when migrating from AWS to Azure

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, performance, amazon-rds

We have a java application running on Tomcat that was hosted on AWS EC2 with a RDS database. We migrated the application to Azure, and the performance dropped significantly. In EC2 we had a md5.large machine (2 CPUs, 8GB) and in Azure we have P2V2 (2 CPUs, 7GB).

The database stayed in RDS, so one of our hypothesis is that we are losing performance with database traffic, since they are on different hosts now. Could that be it? If so, would creating a VPN help in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes, you will now have lag between your application server and the DB. The VPN would not make that much of a difference. What you want is to have your DB close to your application server again. One of the ways to do that would be to either also migrate your RDS to Asure or if your RDS need to stay in AWS then see if you can replicate your DB to Asure (Depends on DB type).

Comment: The main issue is cost, Azure DB is almost 3x more expensive with an equivalent machine compared to AWS. But if it's the only way, then we'll have to deal with it